# Singling out line features for an associated value in a given area in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, least-cost

I have a series of lines that go between many points in a grid fashion, like below.

[image]

Each of these lines has a value associated with it, and I want to pick out a line in each of the "square" areas (they're 500m^2 each) that has the lowest value.

The goal is essentially a series of least cost paths that show the cheapest way to move through each of these spaces, rather than from a specific point to a specific point.

Is there any tool or anything to run that would pick out, say, the line with the lowest value for every 500m^2 of area?

Comment: Does the lines in the same square share some common attribute?

Comment: @BERA they do, they all have a cost value associated with them. They're all in the same attribute table.

Comment: This is a rather ugly data problem -- selection via even a spatial index will be very inefficient. It could take a long time, but intersecting the polygon grid with the lines would make the operation easy.